# how to get new value of state in props of React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have code below.

```
// this is a function which pass to onClick props of a button
const handleDialogClick = () => {
    setDialogOpen({
      title: "Please Choose Language You Want",
      content: (
        <TextField
          label="Text"
          select
          fullWidth
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
          className="border-1 border-cadet-gray"
          onChange={({ target }) => {
            setPendingLanguage(target.value);
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="Chinese">Chinese</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="English">English</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Japanese">Japanese</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
      ),
      onCancelClick: setDialogClose,
      onConfirmlClick: () => {
        // below will get old reference :(
        setLanguage(pendingLanguage);

        setDialogClose();
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleDialogClick}>
        click open dialog
      </Button>

      // some code here...
    </div>
  )
```

And feel confused about how to get new value of state, when the state be used by the props of functional component.

(I know pass a function to set function can get old value, but I'm not supposed to use old value to calculate new value.)

For compelete code, please read [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-avoid-old-reference-gh4qsi?file=/src/pages/Test.tsx)

Comment: please specify in your question which component and prop you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the functions that you store in the state, for example:

```
onConfirmlClick: () => {
  setLanguage(pendingLanguage);
  setDialogClose();
}
```

When the function is stored, the current value of `pendingLanguage` is preserved in the closure. The entire `handleDialogClick` function is recreated on each render, with the current value, but since the modal is open, the functions that are saved in the atom do not.

I'm not familiar enough with Jotai, but I don't think that saving functions in the state is a good way to go. However, there's a workaround, use a ref to store the current value of `pendingLanguage`. The ref is an object, and the stale function in the state would point to the same ref object, and you can get the `current` updated value.

```
const ref = useRef(pendingLanguage);

useEffect(() => {
  ref.current = pendingLanguage;
});

const handleDialogClick = () => {
  setDialogOpen({
    title: 'Please Choose Language You Want',
    content: (
      <TextField
        label="Text"
        select
        fullWidth
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        className="border-1 border-cadet-gray"
        onChange={({ target }) => {
          setPendingLanguage(target.value);
        }}
        defaultValue={pendingLanguage}
      >
        <MenuItem value="Chinese">Chinese</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="English">English</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="Japanese">Japanese</MenuItem>
      </TextField>
    ),
    onCancelClick: setDialogClose,
    onConfirmlClick: () => {
      setLanguage(ref.current);

      setDialogClose();
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the choosen value to a temporary variable declared at the beginning of the function.

```js
import { useAtom } from "jotai";
import { useState } from "react";

import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

import { openDialogAtom, closeDialogAtom } from "../stores/dialogStateAtom";

const Test = () => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("none");
  const [pendingLanguage, setPendingLanguage] = useState("");
  const [, setDialogOpen] = useAtom(openDialogAtom);
  const [, setDialogClose] = useAtom(closeDialogAtom);

  const handleDialogClick = () => {
    let pending = language;
    setDialogOpen({
      title: "Please Choose Language You Want",
      content: (
        <TextField
          label="Text"
          select
          fullWidth
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
          className="border-1 border-cadet-gray"
          onChange={({ target }) => {
            pending = target.value
            setPendingLanguage(target.value);
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="Chinese">Chinese</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="English">English</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Japanese">Japanese</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
      ),
      onCancelClick: setDialogClose,
      onConfirmlClick: () => {
        // below will get old reference :(
        setLanguage(pending);

        setDialogClose();
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleDialogClick}>
        click open dialog
      </Button>

      <form className="border-1 p-5 my-4">
        <Typography
          style={{
            textAlign: "left",
            marginBottom: 16
          }}
        >
          Language: {language} / {pendingLanguage}
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="vocabulary"
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works. But I'm not sure why it can works, could you explain?

Comment: @Tempura I'm not sure how the setDialogOpen works, but when the state changes in Test the components get reRendered but the Dialog is not

Comment: The data passed to setDialogOpen will be passed to Dialog as props.

Yes, you're right. However, what I want to ask is that "why dialog can get new value of pending without being re-render? ".